# What is the default animation for transition between activities?

Tags: android

I want to use this animation that happend when i go from one activity to another in fragments.

I'm using Jetpack Navigation but i can't find this animation in the default ones.

It's like a zoom in and zoom out.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default animation between activities, actually depends on the phone you are executing the app. If you have a Samsung Galaxy Y it will have a different animation that a Huawei P30.

I'm not sure how it would work with jetpack compose since I'm currently learning it, but the following code changes the default animation between activities:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up)
```

Maybe even the names that you can find in R.anim.* could help you somehow.